# If $f$ is a real continuously differentiable function defined on $[0,b]$ then $\int f^2\leq\int f'^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Suppose $f$ is a continuously differentiable real valued function defined on an interval $[0,b]$ with $f(0)=f(b)$. Prove that$$\int_0^bf'(x)^2dx\geq\int_0^bf(x)^2dx$$

I do have some doubts about this because if I consider $f\equiv C$ where $C$ is a constant then the inequality is false. So maybe it holds for non-constant functions only. I do not doubt the authenticity of this problem.

I am a bit stumped on how I should proceed. Please provide just a hint only to help me start. Thanks.

Comment: In your example $f(0)\neq f(3)$

Comment: You quite right - this inequality does not hold for nonzero constant functions. I think there are some additional hypothesis on $f$. I think, if we ask $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then we will be able to prove something similar to the desired inequality.

Comment: What if we assume $f(a)=f(b)=0$? Can you kindly hint at how to start given this extra condition?

Comment: It seems like you should be able to just directly integrate the left side and get $\frac{f(x)^3}{3}|_a^b=0$. It seems like the inequality sign should be switched, and then we could say the right side is positive.

Comment: Are you looking for the Poincaré-Wirtinger inequality? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger's_inequality_for_functions

Comment: Thanks for the reference Siminore. But it seems several of these conditions are missing in my question!! For example, $2\pi$ periodicity is not given, that the integral vanishes is not given, etc.

Comment: So is $f(0) = f(b) = 0$ given, then?

Comment: As your theorem is currently stated, I believe $f(x) = (x-3)^2$ over $[0,6]$ will still work as a non-constant counter-example

Comment: @Robert, No. The final question as it appeared in the semester exam is verbatim presented here.
graydad I am now too sleepy (after long struggle with this problem) to check the validity of your statement and will respectfully take your word for granted. This is immensely strange that a wrong question appeared in the paper.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I felt my counter example was useful for the part of this question where yedaynara says "So maybe it holds for non-constant functions only"

Comment: @graydad oh, I see, I missed that part.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

We have $$f(x) = \int_a^x f'(s)ds = - \int_x^bf'(s)ds,$$hence
$$|f(x)|\le \min\left(\int_a^x |f'(s)|ds,\int_x^b|f'(s)|ds\right)\le \frac 12 \int_a^b|f'(s)|ds.$$
We integrate with respect to $x$ to get
$$\int_a^b f^2(x)dx\le \frac 14 (b-a)\left(\int_a^b|f'(s)|ds\right)^2\le \frac{(b-a)^2}{4}\int_a^b|f'(s)|^2ds$$
By Cauchy-Bunyakowski-Shwartz inequality.

Why the multiplicative constant $\frac{(b-a)^2}{4}$? To think of it, we can not avoid having some information on the domain of integration: its measure has to come into play.

Note that by similar technique we can get the result with the only hypothesis $f(a)=0$. We will lose the factor $\frac 14$, however.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is incorrect but this is an elegant proof to a correct alternative. :)

Comment: Incidentally, I noted that in a disguised way, we do have $f(0)=f(b)=0$. This follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: $f(x) :=\int_0^x f'(t)dt$ hence $f(0)=0$ and therefore, by hypothesis, $f(b)=f(0)=0$.

Comment: @yedaynara first, it's the other way around: $f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^xf's(s)ds$.